# I am having a hard time figuring out what is wrong with my html and js file. I need to count the vowels

Tags: javascript, html

I need to fix this segment of code for a class and I have fixed a number of things but I'm not sure why it doesn't work. It is supposed to count the number of vowels in the phrase and return them as an alert. When I click on the button nothing appears.

***Here's the html. It works fine but added in case I am missing something***

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Vowels</title>   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/easy.css">      
    <script src="p3-vowels.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
         <h1>Count Vowels</h1>

    </header>
    <main>
        <label>Type a phrase here:
            <input type='text' id='textBox'></input>
        </label>
        <button id='countBtn' type='button'>
           Count Vowels (a,e,i,o,u)</button>
        <div id='outputDiv'></div>
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

***here is the JS. It doesn't seem to register the "on.click" at the end of the code***

```
function countVowels() {
    var textBox, phrase, i, pLength, letter, vowelCount;
    textBox = document.getElementById('textBox');
    phrase = textBox.value;
    phrase = phrase.toLowerCase();
    vowelCount = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < phrase.length; i += 1) {
        letter = phrase[i];
        if (letter === 'a' || letter === 'e' || letter === 'i' || letter === 'o' || letter === 'u') {
            vowelCount++;
        }
    }

    alert(vowelCount + ' vowels');
    var outArea = document.getElementById('outputDiv');
    outArea.innerHTML = vowelCount + ' vowels in ' + phrase;
}

function init() {
    alert('init vowels');
    var countTag = document.getElementById('countBtn');
    countTag.onclick = countVowels;
}

window.onload = init();
```

Comment: Note that *input* elements have no closing tag.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `window.onload = init();`, here you are calling `init` method and is assigning the value returned by `init` as the `onload` callback. So when the `init` method is called the `countBtn` is not yet added to the dom resulting in an error like `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null`.

What you really want is to call `init` on the `load` event, so you need to pass the reference to `init` function to `onload`

It should be

```
window.onload = init;
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/54x5zLgh/)